# How to prove Binet theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**How to prove Binet theorem, namely $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ ?**

I've tried with the formulation of two arrays $2 \times 2$,  but could not.

Comment: What is the definition of determinant are you using?

Comment: With $2\times2$ matrices it seems routine: $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} e & f \\ g & h \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ae+bg & af+bh \\ ce+dg & cf+dh \end{bmatrix} $$ and the determinant is $$(ae+bg) (cf+dh) - (af+bh)(ce+dg). \tag 1$$ The product of the two determinants is $$(ad-bc)(eh-gf). \tag 2$$ So the question is whether $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the same thing.  You need to expand both of them. $$\S$$ However, the $n\times n$ case should probably be done somewhat differently. $\qquad$